# how to convert date column while loading using copy command in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have an issue while loading the date column in PostgreSQL using copy command.
actually, columns value, date

```
207     2017-03-08T01:25:34.000Z
207     2017-03-23T09:33:03.000Z
1266    2017-03-08T01:25:35.000Z
1327    2017-03-08T01:25:35.000Z
```

I am unable to read date format like 2017-03-08 01:25:34 using timestamp.

so I used varchar type to read date column.

now I want to create one new column as date formatted and read date like  2017-03-08 01:25:34.

my expected output is

```
207     2017-03-08T01:25:34.000Z    2017-03-08 01:25:34
207     2017-03-23T09:33:03.000Z    2017-03-23 09:33:03
1266    2017-03-08T01:25:35.000Z    2017-03-08 01:25:35
1327    2017-03-08T01:25:35.000Z    2017-03-08 01:25:35
```

how to do it while loading using the copy command in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You can look at the site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152807/how-to-convert-date-column-while-loading-using-copy-command-in-postgresql for the answer.

Comment: @HakanE Wrong Copy paste ???

Comment: might be. but i need the format like YYYY- DD-MM HH:MM:SS

Comment: yes site address is redirect to the same this page. please provide me a correct one

Comment: Why do you have to convert that? That format converts to `timestamp` fine using `psql`.

Comment: No i unable to convert this type to timestamp using psql.
the challenge is i need both old and new  format in the table.
thats y i asked how to convert it and loaded in to the table

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the date modifiers [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html)

I am sure this is applicable to you but you can still check for more options at the link above : 
 `to_timestamp(text, text)` for eg: `to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD MM YYYY HH12:MI:SS')`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it while loading DATA with COPY. But with your existing approach, you can update new timestamp column from existing varchar.
eg:

```
t=# select regexp_replace('2017-03-08T01:25:35.000Z','[TZ]',' ','g')::timestamp;
   regexp_replace
---------------------
 2017-03-08 01:25:35
(1 row)
```

**update** for postgres 8.0 translate should do:

```
update stg.s3_inventory 
set last_modified_format = translate(last_modified,'TZ',' ','g')::timestamp
```

Comment: `update table set new_column = regexp_replace(old_column,'[TZ]',' ','g')::timestamp`

Comment: update stg.s3_inventory set last_modified_format = regexp_replace(last_modified,'[TZ]',' ','g')::timestamp

error message i am getting is
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: invalid input syntax for integer: "g";

Comment: no,no - that's an SQL statement - not a migration or smth - it is pure SQL

Comment: Sorry i am not understand, the question is related to postgresql

Comment: @Manimekalai ah, so it's redshift?.. sorry - totally missed that - updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it wouldn't work:

The test data:

```
$ cat data.csv
207,2017-03-08T01:25:34.000Z
207,2017-03-23T09:33:03.000Z
1266,2017-03-08T01:25:35.000Z
1327,2017-03-08T01:25:35.000Z
```

Creating the test table:

```
$ psql -h server -U postgres -c "create table ts_test(id int,ts timestamp with time zone)" db
CREATE TABLE
```

`\copy`ing the data:

```
$ psql -h server -U postgres -c "\copy ts_test(id,ts) FROM 'data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV" db
COPY 4
```

Querying the result:

```
$ psql -h server -U postgres -c "select * from ts_test" db
  id  |           ts
------+------------------------
  207 | 2017-03-08 03:25:34+02
  207 | 2017-03-23 11:33:03+02
 1266 | 2017-03-08 03:25:35+02
 1327 | 2017-03-08 03:25:35+02
(4 rows)
```

If you'd like to have it in string format as well, first create table:

```
$ psql -h server -U postgres -c "create table ts_test(id int,ts timestamp with time zone, str character varying(100))" db
CREATE TABLE
```

then `\copy` the data and `UPDATE` the `str` column (NOTICE: You probably need some `WHERE` for the `UPDATE`, hence the `UPDATE` is commented out):

```
$ psql -h server -U postgres -c "\copy ts_test(id,ts) FROM 'data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV; --update ts_test set str=ts::character varying(100);" db
UPDATE 4

$ psql -h server -U postgres -c "select * from ts_test;" db
  id  |           ts           |          str
------+------------------------+------------------------
  207 | 2017-03-08 03:25:34+02 | 2017-03-08 03:25:34+02
  207 | 2017-03-23 11:33:03+02 | 2017-03-23 11:33:03+02
 1266 | 2017-03-08 03:25:35+02 | 2017-03-08 03:25:35+02
 1327 | 2017-03-08 03:25:35+02 | 2017-03-08 03:25:35+02
```